# Publish outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, publishing

Is there a way to publish only select days on calendar in outlook. Even if I change the work week to Tuesday and Wednesday in settings for example, when I follow the published link it shows the full week or full month. My service only operates two days a week and I’d like to simplify for clients to just see those two days a week when they click the calendar link. And is there a way to limit to opening ours- showing early
Or Late hours in day takes up a lot of screen when clients only need to see operations between 9-5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear. When I publish a calendar and share it everyday of the month is shared. I want people to only see Tuesdays and Wednesdays, and ideally only see 9-5 time blocks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidance you could Specify the Date Range for the calendar you want to send. [Send an Outlook calendar in an email message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-an-outlook-calendar-in-an-email-message-51ecca41-8fb1-48af-9383-b12e1c0d5512#:%7E:text=Send%20an%20Outlook%20calendar%20in%20an%20email%20message,want%20to%20send%20your%20calendar.%206%20Click%20Send) Check if the solution work for you.

Comment: Do above solution work for you?